# Disclosure of worldbuilding information used in potential publications

Tags: discussion

When I tell people about aspects of Athius they commonly ask why I keep things secret. Telling me that "No one will steal my ideas." or "Nothing is new under the sun."

Yet my concepts, ideas, lore, stories, and characters not only have unmatched value to me personally, but also could have financial value in the future, as I plan on capitalizing on said aspects.

Would disclosing information about my world make them less valuable or am I hindering success by keeping elements a secret?

**EDIT:** This question is a train wreck. To reiterate in (*Hopefully*) more understandable terminology; I am asking if sharing (*To anyone, not just this SE.*) the characters, lore, stories, and other parts of my world **before** any part of it is published takes away from its potential value, or adds to it. (*This question is most likely on the wrong SE, sorry for wasting your time.*)

Comment: Hi welcome to Worldbuilding SE! I'm sure you can find countless of ways to prevent plagiarism from the internet however since you wish to leverage on the community at large to improve your existing world, collaboration is the key if you decided to expand not only your horizon but your circle of like minded friends, Idea is like money which is useless when kept hidden!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if you think your ideas are so unique that they would get stolen and you would be disadvantaged by it in a future work, then by all means keep them to yourself until you are ready to get them published.

But let me remind you of one or two points

- a lot of books have been written so far. It is very likely that something close to your idea and your characters exist somewhere already.
- if you intend to publish your story, how do you plan to convince an editor to accept your book without sharing anything?

You'll note that many famous authors share chapters of their books on-line before getting the whole books published (e.g. GRR Martin). And I don't think it hindered their knowledge.

And Stack Exchange is a Q&A based on the concept of social sharing of knowledge. So if you don't want to share your ideas, then asking questions here is probably not the best place.

Note that ultimately, it is your writing style, the way you present your story, etc. that will make your story a success (and some good marketing).

Most people around here (me included) think that it is possible to share some of their story without compromising their chance to get the whole novel published later. You might also invent some similar case with different characters if you want to protect your main ideas.

Comment: I am not claiming my "ideas" are unique, because they aren't. I mentioned that I get "Nothing new under the sun." comments. I believe that is in-fact true. As far as "sharing of knowledge" goes, I don't have to compromise major element in order to exist in this SE, I can ask relatively general questions about conceptual topics. I am very surprised that almost every answer or comment on this question has mentioned that "I can not exist in this SE, because I do not want to share information I choose to keep secret."

Comment: I might have misconveyed it a bit, but I think my last sentence also goes in that direction. To take some analogy, if you have question about some parts of a code, you don't need to share the whole code on StackOverflow, but a small excerpt, or a simplified reproduction of the intended use is enough. It does not compromise the whole code (and patent, copyright, you name it), while at the same time helping you get precise answers. The same applies here.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell if you are referring to talking about posting on this site (in which case meta, where this has been migrated to, is the right place) or talking about sharing your ideas in general, in which case worldbuilding is not really the right place at all (since we deal with the building of worlds, not the protection of content).

If you are talking about posting on this site, in order to help you get better answers we will need to know things about your setting in order to help inform and refine answers to your questions. Anything you write is subject to the licence on StackExchange, but the words only, not the idea behind them.

If you are talking about sharing your setting with other people (and this isn't on topic here, but I'll answer anyway), then that is down to you. Eventually if you decide to monetise you setting, then you are going to have to reveal it eventually. What you seem to be missing is that the real value of your ideas is in how you use them, rather than in the ideas themselves. If you use them to write a story for instance, the skill that makes them worth something is your skill with writing.

Comment: Deleting this thread seems like the only way to remedy the embarrassment now.

Comment: @Izach It certainly isn't our intention to embarrass.

Comment: @Izach Misunderstandings happen, and from the clarification, seems like it was off topic here. However leaving the question and answers might helps someone on here with a similar question that this does answer in the future. No need to delete. :-)